# What kind of a Switch is this? How can i use this Switch

Tags: motor, switches

[image]

I found this switch in DVD drive, I think its a kind of mechanism which reverses the polarity of the motor. If so How can I use this with arduino uno? THis link might be useful : http://www.instructables.com/id/Disassembling-a-CDDVD-reader-and-reusing-its-parts/?ALLSTEPS

Just to tell you guys I dont have a camera that is why I am linking to another site.

Comment: How do you know it's a switch instead of a motor or something else?

Comment: @EMFields I know its a switch because it has 4 pins saying close and open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't tell from that photo what kind of switch it is. But any kind of switch could be useful in your "junk box" for a future project.  Certainly you should remove it from the circuit board and save it.  Use your DMM to test all the pins to see how the switch works. And take notes so you remember what kinds of parts you are collecting and how they work.